# iframe location.hash #top not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, html

i am having this problem for a week couldn't figureout kindly help!

1.I have a dynamic news page.
2.below the news a comments page attached with an iframe.
3.comments page is having pagenation.

when user navigate trough pages in iframe parent page should scroll to iframes top for that i have used #top in iframe links its working in all browsers except in IE8 (i didn't check in other versions of ie though), so please help me out with it.

thanks,
eeswar

Comment: People are more helpful if you post a code reduction that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the outer page, define a scroller function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function gotop() {scroll(0,0);} </script>
```

Then when you define the iframe, set an onload handler (which fires each time the iframe source loads i.e. whenever you navigate to a new page in the iframe)

```
<iframe id="myframe" onload="try { gotop() } catch (e) {}" 
  src="http://yourframesource" width="100%" height="999" scrolling="auto" 
  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" >  
</iframe>
```

The nice thing about this approach is it means you do not need to make any changes to the pages included in the iframe (and the iframe contents can happily be in another domain - no cross-site scripting issues).